# Gulp-inject crashing server on javascript syntax error

Tags: javascript, error-handling, gulp, gulp-inject

I'm using gulp inject to inject javascript into my html. 
For some reason on syntax errors in where I'm missing a curly brace or parenthesis it decides to crash. I've tried using plumber and even passed a `onError` function to it.

I don't think a server should crash when someone does a bit of js wrong. Does anyone know how I can prevent the web server from shutting down?
My task looks like this

```
return gulp.src('app/index.jade')
    .pipe($.plumber())
    .pipe($.jade({pretty: true}))
    .pipe($.inject(
      gulp.src(files, {read: false}), {
        ignorePath: 'bower_components/',
        starttag: '<!-- inject:bower:{{ext}}-->',
        endtag: '<!-- endinject-->'
      }
    ))
    .pipe($.inject(
      gulp.src('.tmp/*.css', {read: false}), {
        ignorePath: '.tmp/',
        starttag: '<!-- inject:css-->',
        endtag: '<!-- endinject-->'
      }
    ))
    .pipe($.inject(
      gulp.src('.tmp/**/*.js').pipe($.angularFilesort(), {read: false}), {
        ignorePath: '.tmp',
        starttag: '<!-- inject:files:{{ext}}-->',
        endtag: '<!-- endinject-->'
      }
    ))
    .pipe($.inject(
      gulp.src('vendor/**/*', {read: false}), {
        ignorePath: 'vendor/',
        starttag: '<!-- inject:vendor:{{ext}}-->',
        endtag: '<!-- endinject-->',
      }
    ))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp'))
```

I also use plumber in my `serve` task

```
gulp.src(['.tmp', 'bower_components', 'vendor'])
    .pipe($.plumber())
    .pipe($.webserver({
      port: 9000,
      livereload: true,
      proxies: [{
        source: '/api',
        target: 'http://localhost:5555/api'
      }]
    }))
```